# SetCookie on symfony 4.4 blocked by user

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I have a problem related to the creation of a cookie during the 1st step of the sales funnel to be able to register the basketball id ->

```
  private function saveCurrentBasket(Basket $basket)
    {
        try {
            $session = $this->get('session');
            if (!empty($session)) {
                $session->set('basket_id', $basket->getId());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}

        try {
            setcookie('basket_id', $basket->getId(), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // save basket id during 30 days
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}
    }
```

On certain devices, the browser refuses to create the cookie ->

[image]

With the error: This Set-Cookie was blocked due to user preferences.

Do you have any idea to get around this error?

In most cases, cookies work fine.
I try add option -> `'samesite' => 'None'`

Comment: Did you try to set cookie using Symfony Response https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#setting-cookies ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem.

Comment: there are some possible reasons for this, but you can find some reasons when you google the error message. if you already know the reason, please enlighten us. if not, please keep searching. as far as I can tell, we don't have really enough information to help you. is your site embedded somehow or used via js requests? is your domain set in the cookie different from the domain the user is on or is different from the domain the request goes to (sub.domains too).